# Select query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select total comments posted on post. Somehow I am able to do it but the problem is that the total comment will show under each post even if there is no comment on the post.

**Problem:** Not able to get the comment related to post.

**What I want :**

To select total comment related to each post.

**What I try :**

```
SELECT SUM(total_comment) AS comment 
FROM   user_comment 
       INNER JOIN post 
               ON user_comment.image_id = post.id 
WHERE  status = 0
```

```
SELECT SUM(total_comment) AS comment 
FROM   user_comment 
WHERE  status = 0
```

Both the queries return all (total) comment on all posts but I want only show comment related to specific post.

**[My post table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0ERG.png)**

[image]

**[My Comment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tmVC.png)**

[image]

Result look like
[image]

OR

[image]

But i want like

[image]

OR
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I think that most of people don't understand what i am trying to ask? so i am posting  the index.php code, where i access data from data base using while loop, and on the index.php page i want to access the total comment posted on specific post.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('location:signin.php');
}



$smt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post,images WHERE post.Id=images.Id");
$smt->execute();
$smtt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post");
$smtt->execute();
$myres=$smtt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$imgid=$myres->Id;
$imgname=$myres->File_Name;
$qry=$conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(Total_Comment) AS comment FROM user_comment WHERE Image_Id='".$imgid."' AND Image_Name='".$imgname."'");
$qry->execute();
$result=$qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
$total_coment=$result->comment;
?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    include 'nav.php';
}
else
{
    include 'nav-simple.php';
}
?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php include 'right_sidebar.php';?>
<div class="main-container-top" id="masonry-grid">
    <?php while($rows=$smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>

        <div class="col-md-3 grid-item post-col">
<img src="image/<?php echo $rows->Image_Name;?>" data-echo="image/<?php echo $rows->Image_Name;?>" class="post-image"/>

            <h5>Post On &nbsp;<?php echo $rows->Post_Date;?> <span class="pull-right">By <?php echo $rows->Post_By; ?></span> <span class="pull-right">Total Comment <?php echo $total_coment;?></span></h5>

            <a href="post-description.php?id=<?php echo $rows->Id ?>"> <h4><?php echo $rows->Post_Title;?></h4> </a>
            <p>
                <?php echo $rows->Post;?>
            </p>

        </div>


    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
    </div>

<?php include 'footer-content.php';?>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

**Update 2**

*i know the reason that why the query show 2or 3 under each post and the reason is that the query select first or second id from table and count/sum it, but i am unable to resolve the issue, because i want total comment under each post, not one id comments under all post..*

**Note:**

When i run the query on post-description page then it will work fine, but i want to show the number of total comment on each post on index.php page...

**My post-description.php code**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn.php';
$pic_id='';
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $pic_id=$_GET['id'];
}
$comv=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE user_comment.Image_Id='".$pic_id."'  AND user_comment.Status=0 AND user_comment.Comment_Status=1");
$comv->execute();
$fimg=$conn->prepare("SELECT Image_Name From Images WHERE Id='".$pic_id."'");
$fimg->execute();
$gimg=$fimg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$pro=$conn->prepare("SELECT Profile_Picture FROM user_registration WHERE User_Name='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$pro->execute();
$prof_img=$pro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$smt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post,images WHERE post.Id = images.Id AND post.Id='".$pic_id."'");
$smt->execute();
$qry=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Total_Comment) AS comment FROM user_comment WHERE Status=0 AND Image_Id ='".$pic_id."'");
$qry->execute();
$result=$qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
$total_coment=$result->comment;
?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>

<?php include 'nav.php';?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <?php include 'right_sidebar.php';?>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>

    <div class="col-md-9 main-container-top container">
<?php while($rows=$smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):?>
        <div class="media col-md-12 description-post">


           <img src="image/<?php echo $rows->Image_Name;?>" alt="<?php echo $rows->Image_Name;?>" class="img-rounded img-responsive media-left img-description"/>
            <div class="media-body">
               <h4 class="h4 description-heading"><?php echo $rows->Post_Title;?> <small class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-2x"></i> <?php echo $total_coment;?></small></h4>
                <p class="post-text text-justify text-info">

                    <?php echo $rows->Post;?>
            </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
        </div>

        <br/>

            <div class="media col-md-12 comment-section">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['comment-error']))
{
?>
    <span class="alert alert-warning col-md-6 container col-md-offset-3"><?php echo $_SESSION['comment-error']; ?></span>
    <?php
}
unset($_SESSION['comment-error']);
 if(isset($_SESSION['comment-success']))
{
?>
    <span class="alert alert-success col-md-6 container col-md-offset-3"><?php echo $_SESSION['comment-success']; ?></span>
    <?php
}
unset($_SESSION['comment-success']);
    ?>
                <br/>



                <?php while($gcom=$comv->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):?>
                <span class="col-md-1 comment-pic"><img src="profile%20picture/<?php echo $gcom->Profile_Picture;?>" alt="post image" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive comment-img"/></span>
                <div class="media-body  comment-head col-md-10">
                    <h6 class="h6"><a href="#"> <?php echo $gcom->User_Name;?> </a> on <?php echo $gcom->On_Time;?></h6>
                    <p class="comment"><?php echo $gcom->Comment;?></p>
                </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>

        <br/>
        <div class="col-md-12 container">
            <h4 class="description-heading h4 text-muted">Share your thought</h4>
            <br/>
            <form action="comment.php" method="post" class="col-md-12" id="commentForm">
                <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="100" rows="5" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name='picture-name' value="<?php echo $gimg->Image_Name;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="profile-pic" value="<?php echo $prof_img->Profile_Picture;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="pic-id" value="<?php echo $pic_id;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="<?php echo '?id='.$pic_id;?>"/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" name="cmsg" id="" class="btn btn-info"/>
                <br/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br/>



</div>

</div>
<?php include 'footer-content.php';?>
 <?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: yes, i try both way, by Image_Id=Id and by Image_Name=File_Name but both are not working..

Comment: what's common column between this 2 tables..i mean what's reference

Comment: File_Name in post table and Image_Name in comment table are common, and also Id in post table and Image_Id in comment table are common.

Comment: So `Image_id` is actually `post.id`?

Comment: show your sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Query..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_comment INNER JOIN post ON user_comment.Image_Name = post.File_Name WHERE user_comment.Status = 0 AND user_comment.Image_Name = "your image id here";
```

The query work fine, if not for you then just change your way to get data/total comment from mysql.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a separate query for each post you've returned, which is what it looks like you're trying to do, we're just guessing based on the two queries you posted, which both return a single row...

To use that pattern, you'd need to add an additional predicate to the `WHERE` clause to identify *which* `post` you are wanting to return the comment count for.  For example:

```
SELECT SUM(c.total_comment) AS comment
  FROM user_comment c
 WHERE c.status = 0 
   AND c.image_id = 2
```

If there are no rows for a given `image_id`, the `SUM()` aggregate is going to return NULL. You can either handle that in your code, and convert that to a zero, or you can handle that in the SQL, so that it will return zero rather than NULL.  You can use the convenient `IFULL()` function...

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(c.total_comment),0) AS comment
  FROM user_comment c
 WHERE c.status = 0 
   AND c.image_id = 2
```

If the first argument of the IFNULL function is NULL, the function returns the second argument, otherwise it returns the first.

```
IFNULL(a,b)
```

is MySQL-specific shorthand for the ANSI

```
CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN b ELSE a END
```

That answers the question you were asking. How to get a count for a specific post.

---

The other answers here are addressing a problem with this approach... running a separate query for each post is NOT the most efficient or the most scalable design.

Each query execution requires a roundtrip to the database, the database has to parse the SQL text, check that the syntax is valid, do a semantic check, dictionary lookups to verify that the identifiers are valid, the database user has the required privileges, decide on an execution plan, and then run the query, prepare a resultset and return to the caller. And that overhead adds up in a tight loop.

Some of the other answers here are addressing. Rather than running a separate query for each `image_id`, they get the counts in one fell swoop. They do this by adding the `image_id` column to the SELECT list and add a `GROUP BY image_id` to the query... to return a result like this

```
image_id  comment
--------  -------
       2        3
       5        2
```

That would get you back all of the non-zero counts. BUT... you wouldn't run this in the loop that's fetching the rows from post table... you'd run this query first, and store the results into an array, and then for each post that you're putting on the page, you'd do an array lookup to find the count. If one isn't found, then the count is zero.

You could also return zero counts, and store those as well, with a query like this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , IFNULL(SUM(total_comment),0) AS comment 
 FROM post p
 LEFT
 JOIN user_comment c 
   ON c.image_id = p.id
  AND c.status = 0
GROUP BY p.id
```

But that would just be extra rows with zero, still an array lookup, the only difference is you would be finding a match... really no different.

BUT... you don't really want to do that at all.

What the query really hints at is the idea that you don't need a *SEPRATE* query to get the comment count; you can get that in the *SAME QUERY* that returns the rows from `post`.

Just add the outer join to the `user_comment` table, add a `GROUP BY` clause on the unique identifier in the `post` table, and return that aggregate SUM() expression to the SELECT list, along with the columns you are turning from the `post` table. For example:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.Post_Title
     , p.Post
     , p.Filename
     , p.Tag
     , p.Post_Date
     , p.Post_By
     , IFNULL(SUM(c.total_comment),0) AS comment 
 FROM post p
 LEFT
 JOIN user_comment c 
   ON c.image_id = p.id
  AND c.status = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.Post_Date DESC, p.id DESC
```

That's usually a much more scalable design, to return the results in a single query, rather than running a boatload of separate queries.

As another alternative, usually not quite as efficient as the outer join, is to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.Post_Title
     , p.Post
     , p.Filename
     , p.Tag
     , p.Post_Date
     , p.Post_By
     , ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(c.total_comment),0)
           FROM user_comment c
          WHERE c.image_id = p.id
            AND c.status = 0
       ) AS comment
 FROM post p
ORDER BY p.Post_Date DESC, p.id DESC
```

Or, we could also use an outer join operation to an inline view (but this is more applicable in the more general case, when there are more joins involved, and we don't want to double or triple count, though it does return the same result in this case (assuming that `id` is unique in the `post` table,)

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.Post_Title
     , p.Post
     , p.Filename
     , p.Tag
     , p.Post_Date
     , p.Post_By
     , IFNULL(t.total_comment,0) AS comment
  FROM post p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT c.image_id 
              , SUM(c.total_comment) AS total_comment
           FROM user_comment c
          WHERE c.image_id = p.id
          GROUP BY c.image_id
       ) t
    ON t.image_id = p.id
 ORDER BY p.Post_Date DESC, p.id DESC
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on the PHP code you posted, the point is... you only need a **SINGLE** SQL statement.

Just return the derived "total_comment" value for each post, along with each post row, just modify the query (as I indicated in my answer above, there's several possible ways to get that result. Just tell the database to return that count to you. Then your code is much more straightforward. (And for a more deterministic result, add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query.)

For example:

```
$sql="SELECT p.Id
           , p.Post_Title
           , p.Post
           , p.Filename
           , p.Post_Date
           , p.Post_By
           , IFNULL(SUM(c.total_comment),0) AS total_comment
        FROM post p
        LEFT
        JOIN user_comment c 
          ON c.image_id = p.id
         AND c.status = 0
       GROUP BY p.id
       ORDER BY p.Post_Date DESC, p.id DESC"; 

$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while($post = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<br>" . $post->Id;
    echo "<br>" . $post->Post_Title;
    echo "<br>" . $post->Post;
    echo "<br>" . $post->Filename;
    echo "<br>" . $post->Post_Date;
    echo "<br>" . $post->Post_By;
    echo "<br>" . $post->total_comment;
endwhile;
```

This is a very simple example that just echos out the values returned, without all the HTML you actually want to output. It serves to demonstrate that you don't need to muck up your code with a a second or third SQL statement.

And (obviously) this example doesn't address escaping the potential HTML characters stored in the database columns, and doesn't address PDO error handling, either `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRORMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` and appropriate try/catch/finally blocks, or adding individual checks of the return from the `prepare` and `execute` calls. Those are omitted to avoid obfuscating the pattern.

Comment: I've added a FOLLOWUP with an example of the pattern I would use; using a SINGLE SQL statement to return the `total_comment` value along with the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Comment) AS comment FROM user_comment INNER JOIN post ON user_comment.Image_Id = post.Id WHERE Status=0 GROUP BY post.Id
```

I believe `group by` with `inner join` should help you get what you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: it will show the result like http://i.imgur.com/o40sw3T.png which is incorrect because it will show total comment 3 under all post even if there is no comment posted on the post.

Comment: The output of the above query would give you  
3 and  
2.  

I believe this is correct, later the result you show in the image depends on how you make use of the above result in your script.  
Maybe a snippet of code showing how you make use of the query result would help.

Comment: the output depends on the users comment,  mean if there is 10 comment on a post then it would show me comment 10 on the specific post but it would show comment 10 under all post..

Answer (score 0):

you need `left join` and `group by`

This will return zero comments for posts that doesn't have entries in `user_comment` table

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Total_Comment),0) AS comments, post.Id FROM 
post
LEFT JOIN user_comment
ON user_comment.Image_Id = post.Id 
AND Status=0
group by post.Id
```

Comment: Not working for me...  it will show the result like http://i.imgur.com/16Ln2ds.png  for all my post, which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want a result like this ah?

```
Post 
 totalCommand
Post 
 totalCommand
```

Query:

```
SELECT post
FROM (
    SELECT post
        ,postid
        ,1 AS ord
    FROM post

    UNION ALL

    SELECT convert(IFNULL(SUM(Total_Comment), 0), CHAR) AS post
        ,po.postid
        ,2 AS ord
    FROM commenttable co
    RIGHT JOIN posttable po ON po.postid = co.postid
    GROUP BY po.postid
    ) AS tt
ORDER BY postid
    ,ord
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like based on other comments that you've forgotten to include that the original query is after a specific user's comments total. Try adding the `User_Name` to the `WHERE CLAUSE`, assuming a `@username` variable somewhere in your code that you aren't including:

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Comment) AS comment
     , post.Id
FROM user_comment 
INNER JOIN post ON user_comment.Image_Id = post.Id 
WHERE Status=0 
AND user_comments.User_Name = @username
GROUP BY post.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1d383/1/0) with some dummy data.

But a query like this will get you the total number of comments for a single post.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments INNER JOIN posts ON comments.`Image_Name` = posts.`File_Name` WHERE comments.status = 0 AND comments.Image_Name = "956.jpg";
```

Or if you would like to get the total number of comments for each post, you'll execute a query like this:

```
SELECT comments.Image_name, COUNT(*) FROM comments INNER JOIN posts ON comments.`Image_Name` = posts.`File_Name` WHERE comments.status = 0 GROUP BY comments.Image_Name;
```

You can use `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()` and you wouldn't need the `Total_Comment` column any more. As a suggestion, I'd suggest using better relationships between tables (make use of IDs). And obviously, change "956.jpg" to the file name you want to check or change the columns you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand the purpose of having 'Total_comment' in comments table where it could easily be achieved by using 'COUNT()'. For the sake of simplicity I'd be using COUNT() in my example.

```
SELECT
    post.Id,
    post.Post_Title,
    post.Post,
    post.File_Name,
    post.Tag,
    post.Post_Date,
    post.Post_By,
    COUNT(user_comment.id) AS total_post_comment
FROM
    post
    LEFT JOIN user_comment ON (user_comment.Image_Id=post.Id AND user_comment.Status=0)
GROUP BY
    post.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
select p.*, ifnull(total_comments, 0)
from post p
left join (select image_id, SUM(total_comment) AS total_comments
    from user_comment
    where status = 0
    group by 1) t ON t.image_id = p.id
```

This returns all posts, with zero comment totals for those posts without comments (of status 0).

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbf04/1)

Comment: what is p.* and there is no ifnull in query when i use it in php, i provide full code, see update 2 in my question, add your working query in my third query where i try to access the total comment, because i try to add your query but i am failed to get the proper result.

Comment: @Bohemian: OP is failing to grasp this idea that the total_comment can be returned along with the post information, in a single query. And that's the approach the query in your answer demonstrates. (I attempted to explain this idea in my answer, that a second query is *not* required.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(c.Total_Comment),0) AS comments, 
post.Id 
FROM 
post p
JOIN user_comment c ON c.Image_Id = p.Id 
AND c.Status=0
group by p.Id
```